# Install an Outlook 2013 Addin

Tags: inno-setup, outlook-addin, outlook-2013

What are the steps to install an Outlook 2013 Addin, (or even 2016)?

I have a VS2015 app and I can debug it fine, but I am not sure what the steps are to install it as an Addin.

After a bit of research it looks like I need:

- Make sure outlook is not running
- Copy my files to the 'install' directory
- Add an entry in HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Office\Outlook\Addins\MyApp

  - Add Manifest entry
  - Add LoadBehavior, FriendlyName, Description and so on.

Is that correct? Do I need to do something else?

(I am using Inno Setup but it does not really matter, if I know the steps I can add them to a script).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Deploying an Office Solution by Using Windows Installer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc442767.aspx) article describes all the required steps for deploying Office add-ins using MSI installers.

Also you may consider using ClickOnce, see [Deploying an Office Solution by Using ClickOnce](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb772100.aspx).

Comment: Sorry for the delay replying, thanks for the link, the first one helped me create a setup app.